# jQuery replace textbox value with on focusout event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to adding some text to textbox with on focusout event.

**My JS Code is:**

```
jQuery(".search-field input:text").focusout( function() {
    var ckClass = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];

    if(ckClass == 'inp_pa_bedroom'){
        jQuery('.inp_pa_bedroom').val('Hi I am replace');
    }else if(ckClass == 'inp_pa_bathroom'){
        jQuery('.inp_pa_bedroom').val('Hi I am replace');
    }
});
```

I am applying some condition based on this variable: `var ckClass`, but value is replacing and disappear.

I will thankful If someone guide me.

Comment: plz crate http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer about what the desired output is? Are you saying you want to add something to the end of whatever was already in the input? Also, shouldn't you be using `$(this).val(...)` rather than using a class selector?

Comment: use hasClass() to check whether an element has a particular class

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour Okay I am trying to create fiddle.

Comment: can you share your html sample

Comment: @lumos it would be helpful for the community that you revise your previous 12 questions.

Comment: You code is fine, please see code - http://codepen.io/shhade/pen/thFnx
i just removed the input:text from your jquery selector.

Comment: You should probably learn/use a better approach for what you are trying to achieve. Instead of depending on classes.

Comment: @ShhadeSlman Okay great but I am implementing in WordPress so that's why I post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($){ // DOM ready and secure $ alias

 $('.search-field').find(".inp_pa_bedroom, .inp_pa_bathroom").focusout(function(){
    this.value = "Hi I am replace";
 });

 // Other DOM ready code here.
 // Use $ instead of jQuery if you care about your keyboard

});
```

Why not immediately target the desired `class` elements?
Go to the jQuery API docs and there you can find about the `.find()` method.

Comment: please give some explanation to your code so that even a newbie can understand it.

Answer (score -1):

try to use hasClass() function. Use ".on" insted of focusout.

```
jQuery(".search-field input:text").on('focusout', function() {    
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('inp_pa_bedroom')){
        jQuery(this).val('Hi I am replace');
    }else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('inp_pa_bathroom')){
        jQuery(this).val('Hi I am replace');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should really bind jQuery(this) to a variable and re-use it inside the handler.

Comment: How does replacing `.focusout()` with `.on()` help?